# Towards a hard Lewis base like water which is the stronger Lewis acid, silicon tetrachloride or tin (IV) chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, carbon-family

On Pauling scale, both $\ce{Si}$ and $\ce{Sn}$ have electronegativity value of $\mathrm{1.9}$. The difference is in size of d-orbitals which accept lone pair of electrons. $\ce{Si}$ has vacant 3d-orbitals whereas $\ce{Sn}$ has vacant 5d-orbitals.

What will be the Lewis acid strength order?

My Attempt:

In case of $\ce{SiCl4}$ there can be back-bonding between vacant 3d orbitals of $\ce{Si}$ and filled 3d orbitals of $\ce{Cl}$ (though I did not know, how efficient is the back-bonding between 3d-3d orbitals). This introduces partial double bond character in $\ce{Si-Cl}$ bonds, which makes it a weaker acceptor of lone pair of electrons.

In case of $\ce{SnCl4}$ there can be no back-bonding between vacant 5d orbitals of $\ce{Sn}$ and filled 3d orbitals of $\ce{Cl}$. This makes it a stronger acceptor of lone pair of electrons.

${^1}$Hence, the Lewis acid strength order: $\ce{SnCl4 > SiCl4}$
(Though it is not explicit in the mentioned reference.)

It is to be noted that, in case of group- 13 elements, the strength of Lewis acidity order is: $\ce{BCl3 > AlCl3 > GaCl3}$

This is due to difference in electronegativity and size of central atoms.

---

**Reference:**

1. Page 328-329, 4th Edition (Paperback), Shriver & Atkins- Inorganic Chemistry (Oxford)

Comment: Why this question is receiving request to close? Whoever wants to close, at least they can comment the reason!

Comment: Not one of the close voters, but it would probably help if you explained what you think the result should be and the reasoning/research you used to come to that conclusion.

Comment: @Tyberius You can check now.